# Dockerfile to create an image to be used as an container agent in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, dockerfile, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to use a node agent container in Jenkins to run npm instructions on it. So that, I am creating a Dockerfile to get a valid image with ssh and nodejs. The executor runs fine, but when I use npm it says that it doesn't know the command.

The same problem happens when (after building the dockerfile) I do docker exec -it af5451297d85 bash and after that, inside the container, I try to do npm --v (for example).

```
# This Dockerfile is used to build an image containing an node jenkins agent 

FROM node:9.0
MAINTAINER Estefania Castro <estefania.castro@luceit.es>

# Upgrade and Install packages
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get install -y git openssh-server 

# Install NGINX to test.
RUN apt-get install nginx -y

# Prepare container for ssh
RUN mkdir /var/run/sshd && adduser --quiet jenkins && echo "jenkins:jenkins" | chpasswd

RUN npm install

ENV CI=true
EXPOSE 22

CMD ["/usr/sbin/sshd", "-D"]
```

I would like to run npm instructions like npm install, npm publish, ... to manage my project in a jenkinsfile. Could anyone help?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try setting full path of npm command?

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved the problem (after two weeks haha).

```
FROM jenkins/ssh-slave

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install && apt-get clean
RUN apt-get install -y curl 

# Install nodejs    
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs && apt-get install -y nginx
```